# Gtk3 event for noticing when a GtkPaned's split changes

Tags: haskell, gtk3

I'm making a small application, and I'd like to save the size and position of the various adjustable-sized widgets so that when the application is started the next time, the user sees the same thing as when they last quit. I'm having a bit of trouble working out what event I should listen for to know when widgets' sizes are adjusted. Looking around online, it seems like `configure-event` is the right one, but in my test this event doesn't fire when widgets are resized by the user dragging a `GtkPaned`'s split. I've included a minimal example below.

(I know this is a Haskell program, but I tried to avoid any of the fancy features so that it would be readable even by non-Haskell experts. The main thing you might not be able to guess yourself when reading it is that function applications are done with just a space, so what would be `f(x, y, z)` in most other languages is `f x y z` in Haskell.)

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Graphics.UI.Gtk

main :: IO ()
main = do
    initGUI
    window <- windowNew
    on window objectDestroy mainQuit

    eventLog <- labelNew (Just "")
    -- For this minimal example, the widgets have no content. But let's
    -- pretend by just asking for a little space which we'll leave blank.
    widgetSetSizeRequest eventLog 200 200

    uiGraph <- labelNew (Just "")
    widgetSetSizeRequest uiGraph 200 200

    dataPane <- vPanedNew
    panedPack1 dataPane eventLog True True
    panedPack2 dataPane uiGraph False True

    -- Create a callback to print the position of the pane's split. We'll
    -- always say that we didn't end up handling the event and that it should
    -- get propagated to wherever it used to go by returning False.
    let report = liftIO $ do
            print =<< panedGetPosition dataPane
            return False

    on window   configureEvent report
    on eventLog configureEvent report
    on uiGraph  configureEvent report
    on dataPane configureEvent report

    containerAdd window dataPane
    widgetShowAll window
    mainGUI
```

When I run this program, the position of the pane's split is printed when the window is moved around or resized, but not when the split itself is moved.

Is there another event I can listen to that would tell me when that was happening? How can I know when the user is customizing the view so that I can save that information to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to changes of GObject's property using `"notify::{param-name-here}"` signal. In your case it's the `position` property.

That's how it's done with python:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def position(paned, param):
    print(paned.get_position()) # either call object's method
    print(paned.get_property(param.name)) # or obtain property value by name

win = Gtk.Window()
paned = Gtk.Paned()
paned.connect("notify::position", position)
paned.pack1(Gtk.Label.new("abc"))
paned.pack2(Gtk.Label.new("def"))

win.add(paned)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

For the Haskell analog, you can use [`notifyProperty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.15.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Object.html#v:notifyProperty) to get a signal for a given attribute. Although there is a [`panedPosition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.15.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Paned.html#v:panedPosition) attribute with the right type, it doesn't work, because it's not implemented as a named attribute under the hood (not sure why). Instead, you have to build the attribute from raw materials yourself, using [`newAttrFromIntProperty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/glib-0.13.6.0/docs/System-Glib-Properties.html#v:newAttrFromIntProperty). Putting the pieces together, you can add this line to get a report every time the split is moved:

```
on dataPane (notifyProperty (newAttrFromIntProperty "position")) report
```

(The existing `configureEvent` lines from the question are not needed.)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! That gave me the search terms I needed to find the relevant Haskell documentation. I've taken the liberty of adding it to the answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!